# Python: strange issue with my initial tests

Tags: printing

The program looks like this:

```
a=5
print ('Der Wert der Variablen a ist jetzt: ',a)
```

Output look is like this on my Mac

```
('Der Wert der Variablen a ist jetzt: ', 5)
```

It should look like this:

```
Der Wert der Variablen a ist jetzt: 5
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I got correct Message printed when executed in my windows machine. Der Wert der Variablen a ist jetzt:  5

Comment: Thanks, must be some kind of environment issue then - still lost. Thank for your answer I will try it on my windows PC as well.